# How to add "Show when run" option in an ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I created this app and my app's showing up in Siri Shortcut, but my Siri Shortcuts when i run my shortcut it leads me directly to my app and executes the function instead of staying in Siri Shortcut app. It is not showing "Show when run" toggle option under my app's shortcut. How can I add that functionality to my app?

Below is the **Github repository link** of the project:
https://github.com/rebeloper/SiriShortcutsRandomNumber